# Unable to add a Reply to a Discussion Board item. Exception calling "GetItemById" with 1 argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, discussion-board

I have a Discussion Board list inside my team site collection in SharePoint 2013.

Now I want to add some replies to existing Discussion Board items using PowerShell. 
First I have a Discussion with with **Id = 270** as follows:-

[image]

so I wrote this to add a reply to it:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://t****01/" 
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("News & Announcements")
if($list -ne $null)
{ 
$sourceItem = $list.items.GetItemById("270")
$newTopic = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateNewDiscussionReply($list,$sourceItem ); 
$newTopic["Body"] = "Hi";
$newTopic["Modified"] = "12/20/2016 14:01"
$newTopic["Created"] = "12/20/2016 14:01"  
$user = $web.EnsureUser("\test.user")  
$newTopic["Editor"] = $user  
$newTopic["Author"] = $user  
$newTopic.UpdateOverwriteVersion() 

Write-Host $newTopic.Title " discussion topic is created successfully"
}
else
{ 
Write-Host "List does not exists." 
}
```

but I got this exception and the reply was not created:-

> Exception calling "GetItemById" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not
>   fall within the expected range." At line:3 char:1
>   + $sourceItem = $list.items.GetItemById("270")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
>
> Cannot find an overload for "CreateNewDiscussionReply" and the
>   argument count: "2". At line:4 char:1
>   + $newTopic = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateNewDiscussionReply
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodE

so can anyone advice what is the problem inside my PowerShell script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://t****01/" 
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("News & Announcements")
if($list -ne $null)
{ 
    $sourceItem = $list.GetItemById(270)
    $newTopic = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateNewDiscussionReply($sourceItem); 
    $newTopic["Body"] = "Hi";
    $newTopic["Modified"] = "12/20/2016 14:01"
    $newTopic["Created"] = "12/20/2016 14:01"  
    $user = $web.EnsureUser("\test.user")  
    $newTopic["Editor"] = $user  
    $newTopic["Author"] = $user  
    $newTopic.UpdateOverwriteVersion() 

    Write-Host $newTopic.Title " discussion topic is created successfully"
}
else
{ 
    Write-Host "List does not exists." 
}
```

Comment: ok your code worked well .. but do u have a reason why my original code did not work as expected ?

Comment: i think there are 2 reasons - 1) `$sourceItem = $list.items.GetItemById("270")` - here you used string. 2) `$newTopic = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateNewDiscussionReply($list,$sourceItem ); `  - here you should have passed only the sp list item parameter